# Calculating the number of representations of a number that is a sum of 3 squares

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need to write a function head that returns the number of representations of a number as a sum of 3 positive squares.

For example, the only representation of 3 as a sum of 3 squares is 3 = 1+1+1, so the function should return 1 if number = 3. If n is 27, the function should return 2 since 27 has two representations 27 = 25 + 1 +1 or 9+9+9.

This is what I have tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int  numRep(int num);

int main()
{
   int count = numRep(27);
   cout << count;
   return 0;
}

int numRep(int num)
{
   int count = 0, sum = 0;
   int a =1, b=1, c=1;
   while(a*a <= num -2)
   {
     b = 1; 
     while(b*b <= num -2)
     {
       c =1;
       while(c*c <= num -2)
       {
         sum = a*a + b*b + c*c;
         if (sum == num) count++;
         c++;
       }
       b++;
     }
     a++;
   }
   return count/3;
}
```

But I am not getting correct output. Need some guidance... If there is a better method, do suggest..

Comment: Advice: use `for` instead of `while` when you have declaration, condition and incrementation. :)

Comment: For debug purposes, at least, you should output `a`, `b` and `c` every time `sum == num`.

Comment: It seems like you aren't considering 0 to be a perfect square, but that isn't the problem.  I think the problem is with the doubles counting - for solutions where each number is different (like 25+1+1), dividing count by 3 is an adequate solution, but if they are the same (9+9+9) it is only counted once.  What you might want to do is keep track of the correct solutions, and then go back and take out the ones that are the same, but in different orders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a good starting point:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int count_sum_of_squares(int n)
{
  int count=0;

  // We only need to test numbers up to and including the square root of n.
  // Also, we want to impose an ordering on [a, b, c] to consider 
  // combinations and NOT permutations.
  for (int a=1; a<=int(sqrt(n)); ++a)
    for (int b=1; b<=a; ++b)
      for (int c=1; c<=b; ++c)
        if (a*a+b*b+c*c==n) // If the squares of {a, b, c} add up to n
          ++count;          // then this is a case that should be counted

  return count;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << 3 << ': ' << count_sum_of_squares(3) << '\n';
  std::cout << 14 << ': ' << count_sum_of_squares(14) << '\n';
  std::cout << 27 << ': ' << count_sum_of_squares(27) << '\n';
  std::cout << 866 << ': ' << count_sum_of_squares(866) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @ScottMermelstein take the squareroot of n and make a that

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn Now you need a typecast, and/or a `ceil` :-)

Comment: @Scott, I added the explicit cast back to int. There is no need for a `ceil`, it only needs to be <= the floor and int truncation does this just right for positive integers.

Comment: Note that you can skip the 3rd loop by checking if `n - a*a - b*b` is a perfect square. Of course this requires taking an expensive `sqrt`, but it converts an O(N^3/2) algorithm to O(N), so it's worth it for large N.

Comment: for (int a=1; a<=int(sqrt(n)); ++a)
relies on a compiler optimisation to ensure the square root is calculated only once. Better coding practice would be to calculate the square root before the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of searching from 1 to num - 2, you should only search from the current index loop above. That way, you don't repeat any terms.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int  numRep(int num);

int main()
{
   int count = numRep(27);
   cout << count << endl;
   return 0;
}

int numRep(int num)
{
   int count = 0, sum = 0;
   int a =1, b=1, c=1;
   while(a*a <= num -2)
   {
     b = a; 
     while(b*b <= num -2)
     {
       c =b;
       while(c*c <= num -2)
       {
         sum = a*a + b*b + c*c;
         if (sum == num) {
            count++;
         }
         c++;
       }
       b++;
     }
     a++;
   }
   return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting all the permutations, and you want all the combinations.

Example:  numRep(14) will give you 6, when I think you want it to only have 1.

```
a = 1, b = 2, c = 3
a = 1, b = 3, c = 2
a = 2, b = 1, c = 3
a = 2, b = 3, c = 1
a = 3, b = 1, c = 2
a = 3, b = 2, c = 1
```

You'll need to keep track of your answers, preferably sorted with a-c going from lowest to highest, and don't increment your count if it already exists.

Comment: ... or you design your loop to eliminate redundancies, as Michael did.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
 int numRep(int num){

   int count = 0;

   for(int a = 1; a * a <= num ; ++a)
        for(int b = a; b * b <= num ; ++b)
            for(int c = b; c * c <= num ; ++c)
                if (a*a + b*b + c*c == num) 
                    count++;

   return count;
}
```

Only start with `b` from `a`, and with `c` from `b` so you won't count twice the same solution.

The complexity of this is `O(N*sqrt(N))` I think.

Comment: Nice brute force approach. Observation: you only need to test for `a*a < num`, not "or equal to" because both b and c won't ever be zero. You can also easily cache a*a, b*b and their sum. There may be other micro-optimizations like this, but I don't think any of them will make a big splash on your algorithm ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just start second loop from `a`. And you don't need a third loop at all. `c = sqrt(num - a*a - b*b)`. If this calculated `c` is an integer, then it counts.